# Требуется помощь в написании цикла

Tags: php, php5

Добрый день. Имеется база со структурой

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_city` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `level` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `catalog_city` VALUES ('1', '0', 'Россия', '0');
INSERT INTO `catalog_city` VALUES ('2', '0', 'Беларусь', '0');
INSERT INTO `catalog_city` VALUES ('3', '2', 'Минск2', '0');
INSERT INTO `catalog_city` VALUES ('4', '1', 'Минск2', '0');
```

На самом деле количество записей измеряется тысячей, а уровень вложения не известен. Требуется проставить уровень вложения в колонку level (от 0 и до последней вложенности). Как это сделать циклом?

Answer (score 2):

Вижу такой алгоритм:

1. **Левел** = 0
2. **Массив родителей** = [0]
3. Присвоить столбцу level значение **Левел** для  parent_id IN **Массив родителей**
4. Получить все значения id для parent_id IN **Массив родителей**
5. **Левел** + 1
6. **Массив родителей** = массиву id из 4 пункта
7. Если **Массив родителей** не пустой перейти к 3 пункту

Answer (score 1):

```html
function update_level($id) {
 global $db, $tabl_prefix, $city_i_down;
 if($id > 0) {
  $wh = "id = '{$id}'";
 } else {
  $db->query("UPDATE `" . $tabl_prefix . "_city` SET level = '1'");
  $wh = "parent_id > '0'";
    }
 $result = $db->query ( "SELECT level, id, parent_id FROM `" . $tabl_prefix . "_city` WHERE {$wh}" );
 while ( $row = $db->get_row ( $result ) ) {
  $suffix = 1;
  $parent_id = $row['parent_id'];
  if ( $parent_id > 0 ) {
   do {
    $suffix++;
    $parent_id = $city_i_down[$parent_id] ['parent_id'];
   } while ( $parent_id > 0 );
  }
  $db->query("UPDATE `" . $tabl_prefix . "_city` SET level = '{$suffix}' WHERE id = '{$row['id']}'");
 }
}
```

Вот готовая функция.

- `$id` - входной ID (если задан)
- `$db` - класс для выполнения запроса (класс mysqli)
- `$tabl_prefix` - просто префикс к таблице. Это видно.
- `$city_i_down` - это многомерный массив, содержащий данные всей таблицы. Он формируется вот так.

```html
$city_i_down = array ();
$result = $db->query ( "SELECT * FROM `" . $tabl_prefix . "_city`);
while ( $row = $db->get_row ( $result ) ) {
    $city_i_down [$row ['id']] = array ();
    foreach ( $row as $key => $value )
        $city_i_down [$row ['id']] [$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Без конкретики по глобальным переменным, это не **готовая** функция. Ну и отвечать портянкой кода без комментариев - плохая практика.

Comment: Внес пояснения в ответ